# Question about sign of limit

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $X$ be some subset of euclidean space  and for the bounded function $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ and let $f(x) = \sup f(X)$.   Is the limit

$$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(x+ta) - f(x)}{t}$$

if it exists guaranteed to be nonpositive?

Comment: Hint:  Suppose $f$ is constant.

Comment: I have edited my question

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $X=[0,1]$ and $f(x)=x$. Then $f(1)=\sup f(X)$, and

$$
\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(x+ta)-f(x)}t=\frac{x+ta-x}t=a\;,
$$

which can be positive, zero or negative depending on $a$.

By the way, I think one question mark would have been enough.